# All text is saved in one line

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

So, I was trying to use NLTK from Python to do a part of speech tagging to a text file. 
This is the code I used

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
f = open('all.txt')
raw = f.read()
text = word_tokenize(raw)
paosted = nltk.pos_tag(text)
saveFile = open('ol.txt', 'w')
saveFile.write(str(paosted))
saveFile.close()
```

The code did work, but the problem is that it saved all the text in one single line as shown in the attached picture.  [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUYI8.png) .. I know I should be using a "\n" function, but I am a novice in python and have no idea how to do it, so any help would be appreciated :) ..

```
                      -------- UPDATE -----------
```

WELL, People have been really helpful and offered some solutions i.e., this code:

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
f = open('all.txt')
raw = f.read()
text = word_tokenize(raw)
paosted = nltk.pos_tag(text)
saveFile.write(str(paosted).replace('),' ,  '),\n'))
saveFile.close()
```

But I still need to have it in the form of a paragraph because I am going to use it latter in a concordance software. Please have a look at this screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU1NW.png

Comment: What is your question exactly? Why not add "\n" to your string where you want linebreaks?

Comment: As I pointed out, I do not know how (or where) to add the "\n" in my code. I am a novice in Python.

Answer (score 0):

`paosted` is a list of tuple you can iterate over it and write each tuple to a line

**Ex:**

```
paosted = nltk.pos_tag(text)
saveFile = open('ol.txt', 'w')
for line in paosted:
    saveFile.write(str(line)+ "\n")
saveFile.close()
```

Comment: How about `saveFile.write("\n".join(paosted))`?

Comment: @RaunaqJain Jain I did that! and I recieved this error:                            TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found

Comment: @Rakesh That was really helpful! Thanks! But instead of having separate lines, I now have each word in a line.. I need to have the format of paragraphs with the tagging.

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Updating my answer accordingly to,

```
temp = []
for i in paosted:
    temp.append("_".join(i))

" ".join(temp)
```

Comment: Well.. that changes a lot.. but still I need to have it in the form of a paragraph because I am going to use it latter in a concordance software. Please have a look at this screenshot: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tU1NW.png

Comment: You should update the question with that! Check out [minimal] [1]:

Comment: I've updated the question.. I think I didn't express myself quite well at the beginning. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I followed some of your instructions and the best result I got was with this code:

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
f = open('all.txt')
raw = f.read()
text = word_tokenize(raw)
paosted = nltk.pos_tag(text)
saveFile = open('output.txt', 'w')
saveFile.write(str(paosted).replace("('.', '.')" ,  "\n"))
saveFile.close()
```